# What is an easily hackable C preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to add a small feature to a C preprocessor, but for that, I need one that is easy to understand and can easily be modified. Specifically, I am looking for the following criteria:

- small codesize
- well-documented
- easy to modify
- free software (I want to be able to distribute the modified code without paying fees or so.)

I have already found [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/), which includes a preprocessor and is fairly small but, as far as I can see, lacks good documentation on how preprocessing is implemented. Should I just try to understand how tcc does it or does a better fit exist?

Comment: We fight for a preprocessorless C! (+1 though)

Comment: You may already know, but I should point out that C preprocessing is described in minute detail in the standard. Have you checked whether section 5.1.1.2 in the C99 standard could serve as TCC's preprocessor's documentation? There is little incentive to do it differently than specified there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=20396 or http://mcpp.sourceforge.net/

Seems good to me!

Comment: The blitzbasic one isn't compatible with normal C preprocessors, but mcpp looks promising, thanks. :)